# Separate list of lists to tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, zip, lzip

```
Input    : [['1538', '1'], [False], [True], ['firm']]
Output : [('1538', False, True, 'firm'),
          ('1', False, True, 'firm')]
```

lzip is giving only the first row

```
In [91]: lzip(*[['1538', '1'], [False], [True], ['firm']])
Out[91]: [('1538', False, True, 'firm')]
```

Also it expects all args to be an iterable. I wanted this to handle even if the input is like,
`[['1538', '1'], False, True, 'firm']`

What is the easy way to do this

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
list(product(*[['1538', '1'], [False], [True], ['firm']]))
#[('1538', False, True, 'firm'), ('1', False, True, 'firm')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Building upon [ExplodingGayFish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12129146/explodinggayfish), if you want to be able to handle the second case as well:

```
from itertools import product

Input = [['1538', '1'], [False], [True], ['firm']]
Input2 = [['1538', '1'], False, True, 'firm']

def sep(iterable):
    new_iter = (item if isinstance(item,list) else [item] for item in iterable)
    return list(product(*new_iter))

print(sep(Input))
print(sep(Input2))
```

Output:

```
[('1538', False, True, 'firm'), ('1', False, True, 'firm')]
[('1538', False, True, 'firm'), ('1', False, True, 'firm')]
```